# Is it possible to limit which fields get persisted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I've got a User model that is utilizing mongoid.  The model has a password, password_confirmation and encrypted_password field.  The password and password_confirmation fields are populated at runtime with the value the user would type on the screen when creating a new user.  When I persist, I don't want to persist the unencrypted password values, I only want to persist the value contained in encrypted_password.  Is this possible?  Is there something I can use to denote certain fields as not being persistable?

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: use devise, why are you reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

Model only needs the password field and use a before_filter:

```
def User
  before_save :hash_password
  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
  def hash_password
    #todo: improve by adding a salt
    self.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(self.password)
  end
end
```

Notes:

1. Passwords should be stored using a one-way hash, and so passwords should not be 'decryptable'
2. Use a salt (a random value) and add that to the password before passing it to the `hexdigest()`. Store the salt in the database as well - say a column called `password_salt`.
3. `password_confirmation` is a virtual attribute and does not need to be defined in the model (rails will manage the details internally)